# How to Ignore Some DataMember on Runtime JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

//i want some data members to serialize not all based on some condition.

```
class Days
{
}

class Weeks
{
}

class Months 

{
List<Days> listDays=new List<Days>();
List<Months > listMonths=new List<Months >();
}

class Year
{
Months m=new Months();
  if(day=="monday")
{
listDays.add(day)
}

}

class Year
{
Months m=new Months();
  if(day=="monday")
{
listDays.add(day)
}


  i dont want to empty here months that i not used so i want to remove when json created
```

{  "listMonths": [],"listDays": [ "Monday"]}

"listMonths": [] give me some solution so i can neglate unnecessary data member while serialization.

Comment: Hi, fix the indentation of the code, it will be much easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the overloaded method of `SerializeObject` to exclude null objects. something like below

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jSONDocument, 
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, 
                        new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                        });
```

Unfortunately, there is no serializer option to ignore empty collections. however, you can use `DefaultContractResolver` to ignore empty collection

```
public class EmptyCollectionContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        Predicate<object> shouldSerialize = property.ShouldSerialize;
        property.ShouldSerialize = obj => (shouldSerialize == null || shouldSerialize(obj)) && !IsEmptyCollection(property, obj);
        return property;
    }

    private bool IsEmptyCollection(JsonProperty property, object target)
    {
        var value = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(target);
        var collection = value as ICollection;
        if (collection != null && collection.Count == 0)
            return true;

        if (!typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            return false;

        var countProp = property.PropertyType.GetProperty("Count");
        if (countProp == null)
            return false;

        var count = (int)countProp.GetValue(value, null);
        return count == 0;
    }
}
```

And change `SerializeObject` to

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jSONDocument,
                    Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new EmptyCollectionContractResolver(),
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    });
```

Comment: Thank You for your valuable suggestion Its Working But only Case Of String Type Datatype not Object or int or Array. @Krishna Mohan Varma

Comment: @HIREN, Unfortunately, there is no serializer option to ignore empty collections. we can inject `ContractResolver ` to ignore empty collections. Check the above code. hope this help !